# PySpark drop-dupes based on a column condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Still new to Spark and I'm trying to do this final transformation as cleanly and efficiently as possible.

Say I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
+------+--------+                  
|ID    | Hit    |                  
+------+--------+
|123   |   0    | 
|456   |   1    |
|789   |   0    |     
|123   |   1    |   
|123   |   0    | 
|789   |   1    |   
|1234  |   0    |
| 1234 |   0    |   
+------+--------+
```

I'm trying to end up with a new dataframe(or two, depending on what's more efficient), where if a row has a 1 in "hit", it cannot have a row with a 0 in hit and if there is, the 0's would be to a distinct level based on the ID column.

Here's one of the methods I tried but I'm not sure if this is 
1.  The most efficient way possible
2. The cleanest way possible

```
dfhits = df.filter(df.Hit == 1)
dfnonhits = df.filter(df.Hit == 0)
dfnonhitsdistinct = dfnonhits.filter(~dfnonhits['ID'].isin(dfhits))
```

Enddataset would look like the following:

```
+------+--------+                  
|ID    | Hit    |                  
+------+--------+
|456   |   1    |    
|123   |   1    |   
|789   |   1    |   
|1234  |   0    |  
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you add your output DataFrame too? That way it would be tad easy.

Comment: What if an ID has only zeros. In this case you want both IDs?

Comment: if hit has only 0/1 then something like `df.groupBy("ID").agg(max("Hit"))`.. should do the trick... Note: Syntax is scala but similar thing can be done in python as well

Comment: @cph_sto  I added the missing detail, There's one piece I neglected to point out in regards to distinct values.  What was happening before was, when I dropped duplicates, it would outright drop some 0's, 1's, etc.

Comment: My code works for that, just added `.dropDuplicates()` to remove `(1234,0)` appearing two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Creating the Dataframe.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(123,0),(456,1),(789,0),(123,1),(123,0),(789,1),(500,0),(500,0)],
                                ['ID','Hit']) 
df.show()
+---+---+ 
| ID|Hit| 
+---+---+ 
|123|  0| 
|456|  1| 
|789|  0| 
|123|  1| 
|123|  0| 
|789|  1| 
|500|  0| 
|500|  0| 
+---+---+
```

The idea is to find the `total` of `Hit` per `ID` and in case it is more than 0, it means that there is atleast one `1` present in `Hit`. So, when this condition is `true`, we will remove all `rows` with `Hit` values 0.

```
# Registering the dataframe as a temporary view.
df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df=sqlContext.sql(
    'select ID, Hit, sum(Hit) over (partition by ID) as sum_Hit from table_view'
)
df.show()
+---+---+-------+ 
| ID|Hit|sum_Hit| 
+---+---+-------+ 
|789|  0|      1| 
|789|  1|      1| 
|500|  0|      0| 
|500|  0|      0| 
|123|  0|      1| 
|123|  1|      1| 
|123|  0|      1| 
|456|  1|      1| 
+---+---+-------+
df = df.filter(~((col('Hit')==0) & (col('sum_Hit')>0))).drop('sum_Hit').dropDuplicates()
df.show()
+---+---+ 
| ID|Hit|  
+---+---+ 
|789|  1| 
|500|  0| 
|123|  1| 
|456|  1|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Ok, this works.  I wouldn't have thought of doing it this way however the one thing I had to change(which I failed to mention) was .dropDuplicates('ID') due to having 30+ columns all with differing values.  This is a very interesting way of doing thinking through the problem so I'm glad to have seen it done this way.

Comment: I am happy that it solved the problem for you. The way you were doing is actually the first thing that comes to mind, but to do that one needs to make many `joins`, something which can be done easily in one or two lines in `SAS`. `PySpark`, I feel has till a long way to go to make it easy for users.